# Building symfony 3 ecommerce site

Tags: php, symfony, bundle, symfony-3.1, symfony-3.2

I've started learning symfony framework and I thought that it would be a great practice to build eCommerce site, but I found it difficult finding information about building it.

My questions are:
Witch bundles would be useful for building an eCommerce site?
Maybe there are some sources where I could find code examples how the pros build their projects?

Comment: Sadly there are no bundles that are witches..!!

Answer (score 0):

[Sonata Project](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/) has several bundles that would aid in the development of your eCommerce website. One of these is specifically for eCommerce.